# Highstock return to panning after using zoom

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

Hello Highstock Community,

How can I turn off zooming so a user can pan the graph again after zooming in using highstock tools?

Eg looking at [this highstock sample](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/stock-tools-gui) we user likes to do the following:

1. Zoom in with the zoom buttons on the left
2. Pan again (no way to leave zooming again.)

Thx really appreciate your help!

```js
Highcharts.getJSON('https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/aapl-ohlcv.json', function (data) {

    // split the data set into ohlc and volume
    var ohlc = [],
        volume = [],
        dataLength = data.length,
        i = 0;

    for (i; i < dataLength; i += 1) {
        ohlc.push([
            data[i][0], // the date
            data[i][1], // open
            data[i][2], // high
            data[i][3], // low
            data[i][4] // close
        ]);

        volume.push([
            data[i][0], // the date
            data[i][5] // the volume
        ]);
    }

    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
        yAxis: [{
            labels: {
                align: 'left'
            },
            height: '80%',
            resize: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }, {
            labels: {
                align: 'left'
            },
            top: '80%',
            height: '20%',
            offset: 0
        }],
        tooltip: {
            shape: 'square',
            headerShape: 'callout',
            borderWidth: 0,
            shadow: false,
            positioner: function (width, height, point) {
                var chart = this.chart,
                    position;

                if (point.isHeader) {
                    position = {
                        x: Math.max(
                            // Left side limit
                            chart.plotLeft,
                            Math.min(
                                point.plotX + chart.plotLeft - width / 2,
                                // Right side limit
                                chart.chartWidth - width - chart.marginRight
                            )
                        ),
                        y: point.plotY
                    };
                } else {
                    position = {
                        x: point.series.chart.plotLeft,
                        y: point.series.yAxis.top - chart.plotTop
                    };
                }

                return position;
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'ohlc',
            id: 'aapl-ohlc',
            name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
            data: ohlc
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            id: 'aapl-volume',
            name: 'AAPL Volume',
            data: volume,
            yAxis: 1
        }],
        responsive: {
            rules: [{
                condition: {
                    maxWidth: 800
                },
                chartOptions: {
                    rangeSelector: {
                        inputEnabled: false
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#container {
    max-height: 800px;
    min-height: 75vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.highcharts.com/css/stocktools/gui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.highcharts.com/css/annotations/popup.css">


<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/data.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/indicators/indicators-all.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/drag-panes.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/annotations-advanced.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/price-indicator.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/full-screen.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/stock-tools.js"></script>

<div id="container" class="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update #1

I understood you better now I think.

Is this what you wanted?
Can use the zoom tool from the toolbar, then pan using 'alt' + mouse click & drag.

https://jsfiddle.net/marensiusb/rjs60a37/3/

---

If I understood you correctly, you want to:

1. Zoom in
2. Pan
3. Then zoom out

You can zoom in using the [rangeSelector](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector) (1m, 3m, 6, YTD, 1y, all), then pan and zoom out using the rangeSelector ('ALL').

You can also disable the rangeSelector and enable `chart.zoom` and `chart.pan`
Then the user can pan using alt + mouse and reset using the 'Reset Zoom' button.

https://jsfiddle.net/marensiusb/z6tn28w4/4/

Comment: Hi Marensius, usage asndescriped in the question. Zoom in via HighStock zoom buttons. When panning again to move forward and backward in time. Navigator or range selector ar not accepted solutions, as we are optimizing on ux and already implemented them, but users explicitly struggle with the zoom and zoom button usage and do not use the others.